# UserAddressRequest returning result code of 1 in onActivityResult when it worked earlier this week

Tags: android, google-api

I am using a UserAddressRequest in an android application to prompt the user to select an address with the following code.

```
if (HomeActivity.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) { // Google API is connected
        // Building request for UserAddress
        UserAddressRequest request = UserAddressRequest.newBuilder().build();
        // Submitting the request for UserAddress object
        Address.requestUserAddress(HomeActivity.mGoogleApiClient, request,
                HomeActivity.REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ADDRESS_LOOKUP);

    } else { // Google API is not connected
        if (!HomeActivity.mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // Connect Google API if not connecting already
            HomeActivity.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

    }
```

in my onActivityResult I am getting the correct requestCode but a result code of 1 which previously I was not obtaining (Was getting -1 and everything worked earlier this week).  I have not changed anything in the code and now it is not working.  Has anyone ran into this problem or have an idea of where to go from here?

Comment: I went and pulled the source code for the google android-pay test project called androidpay-quickstart (the awesome bike store app) and it is not working either for the UserAddressRequest.

Comment: I tested this on L and N and it works but on M it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I brought this up in an email to android support and they passed it on to someone from their team.  I received a quick email saying that the problem was being looked into.  Then the following week ( last week ) the call was working again as it should on android m again.  I don't know if it was a problem on their end or not but it seems to be working normally again.